# DB2 Installation on RHEL 9.2 - error while loading shared libraries: libdb2ure.so.1

Tags: installation, server, db2, rhel

I am facing an issue trying to install DB2 (Server 11.5.8) on RHEL 9.2.
I have run the db2prereqcheck which passed all critical tests.

However when trying to install DB2 using either **db2setup** or **db2_install** I am faced with the following error.

*/root/db2.tmp.181304/db2/linuxamd64/install//db2iure: error while loading shared libraries: libdb2ure.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

I have verified that the *libdb2ure.so.1* library is available in the install package, and is available under the same directory as db2iure.

The error suggests a permission issue, however the install is being run as root.

Does anyone have any suggestion for this?

Comment: If you find a workaround, you might find more issues. Db2 v11.5.8.0 server is not "supported" on RHEL9, as yet. That means, if you get a problem specifiec to RHEL9 and you have an IBM support contract, IBM is able to say "not supported".  Allegedly, support by Db2 server for RHEL9 will appear in the "next major release" which looks like early 2024 maybe.

Comment: Meanwhile you might check if `ldd` and similar tools reports any more detail for that library, also checking if LD_LIBRARY_PATH having that containing-directory included, if that makes any difference etc.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to fapolicyd being active. Again you may want to double check RHEL 9 is supported for this release

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=security-fapolicyd-software-framework-linux